# Create events in Android using Facebook old api

Tags: android, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I have this code

```
        JSONObject event = new JSONObject();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("method","events.create");
        event.put("name", "name");
        event.put("location", "Address");
        event.put("start_time", "2011-12-15T10:13:00");
        event.put("end_time", "2011-12-15T10:20:00");
        event.put("privacy_type", "OPEN");
        event.put("event_info", "INFO");
        Log.d(TAG,"evento "+mFacebook.request(bundle));
```

and this error...

```
             {"error_code":100,"error_msg":"The parameter event_info is                                                       required","request_args":   [{"key":"access_token","value":"asdasdasd"},{"key":"method","value":"events.create"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

i'm using the old api...if you know create events in Android using the new Api I will be grateful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi benoffi7.. i am also trying to add events from my app. Am not getting any idea. can u pls post some code.. Thank you

Comment: Hi wolverine! There is an correct answer below my question. Try to do that in your app.

Comment: am also getting the same error when i post the event. can u post me sample cod efor that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [event](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) using [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/): send POST request. I try with parameters: name, start_time, end_time, description, privacy_type.
If I right understood requered params only name and start_time. If you not set end_time, it will be equal start_time + 3h. By default privacy is OPEN.
But I not understood, what you want from event_info?
You can add to POST field location. Or you want send extend information with facebook object as some place (as in Graph API venue)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your syntax. event_info tag take jsonObject not string. You have to pass Json object as parameter for event_info. This is my working code . Try this.

```
JSONObject json = null;

                      try {
            json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("privacy_type", "OPEN");
            json.put("name", mEventName.toString());
            json.put("start_time",mCurrentDateTime);
            json.put("end_time", mExpiryDateTime);
            json.put("description",mEventName.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "events.create");

    params.putString("event_info", json.toString());
    String response = "";
    try {
        response = facebook.request(params);
        Log.d("gaurav", "response of create events ="+response);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is working fine for me.I hope it will work for you.