# Android Facebook creating events using Graph ApI

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an event using Graph Api with the following code

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putString("name", "Super");
 params.putString("start_time", "2013-02-14T17:30:00");

 Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/events", params, "POST",
                             new EvenListener(), null);
```

But I am getting the following Facebook Error";#100 invalid parameter".
What I have missed ?. Can you please help me out?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528970/create-events-in-android-using-facebook-old-api

Comment: Hi Raja I followed that answer only. But still I am getting this error

Comment: Is this a typo? new EvenListener()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your start_time is not a valid ISO-8601 format.

You need to specify the timezone offset.

edit: hrmmm it seems that facebook MIGHT actually still be accepting without the offset, but it is deprecated. It's possible you are working with a future version of the facebook sdk enabled that is stricter?

Although I don't think it is accepted for new invites anyway

"Local-time (deprecated, e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00'): legacy events that do not have any timezone information. This format is deprecated, but continues to be returned due to legacy events that are still in the system."

from

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/